# apache redirect problems with secure connection

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

in my default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin my.name@someplace.cool
        ServerName the-checkout-tech.com:443
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

        DocumentRoot /srv/www/the-checkout-tech.com/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /srv/www/the-checkout-tech.com/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.the-checkout-tech\.com$ [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.the-checkout-tech\.com$ [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^li263-156\.members\.linode\.com$ [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^173\.255\.253\.156$
                RewriteRule (.*) https://the-checkout-tech.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

https www resolves to https /  - works fine

but the rest come up with privacy errors in chrome, and fair enough for that url, I want a redirect like www manages.

`https://test.the-checkout-tech.com` - priv error

`https://li263-156.members.linode.com` - priv error

Worked fine in http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your SSL certificate is for `the-checkout-tech.com` and not related subdomains. So when you go to something like `test.the-checkout-tech.com` the SSL issued for `the-checkout-tech.com` will not match. So some browsers will show warnings. Others won't.

If this is a genuine concern of yours, your only real solution is to get SSL certificates for each subdomain or just get a wildcard certificate to cover all bases.

Comment: hmm so a crawler would still get redirected, i guess that's all that matters. Thanks

Comment: If all you care about is the crawler response, you should be good. But the issue of SSL mismatch for subdomains is basically an arbitrary one that centers around how browsers and crawlers respond to mismatches. For all you know Google’s crawlers one day will decide to not honor mismatched SSL & you will only find out via their webmaster tools after the fact. But in general, I will say that you are good for crawlers. The concern seems to be centered around human-based browsing & the potential for fraud. Not content SEO indexing.